# How to count sequential repeats of a value (allowing for one skip)

Tags: r, statistics, sequence

I am trying to produce a variable that counts how many times a "1" appeared sequentially in the preceding rows for a different variable. However, I need the count to persist even if there is one row missing a 1. (i.e., 10111011 should register as an 8). The code I use to count sequential 1s is:

The following code provides an example of the kind of thing I'm trying to do:

```
input <- c(1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1)
dfseq <- data.frame(input)
dfseq$seq <- sequence(rle(as.character(dfseq$input))$lengths)
```

which produces the following dataframe:

```
data_struc <-
  structure(list(
    input = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1),
    seq = c(1L,
            1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-11L),
  class = "data.frame")
```

However, I want the sequence to allow for one row of "failure" on the sequence, such that it continues to count consecutive ones even if one row contains a 0 and then the 1s continue. It should only stop counting once two 0s appear consecutively

Comment: It's difficult to understand the problem without reproducible data. Could you add a sample of your data that reproduces the problem (you can use for instance `dput`).

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'm new at this. I tried to edit the question to be more helpful, including using the dput function. I tried to follow instructions for how to get the DF to actually paste properly, but it still just looks like rcode. Not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: No worries. Another thing you can do to add to your dataframe the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a lagged variable with an OR condition:

```
library(dplyr)
dfseq %>% mutate(
  cum_result = cumsum(input == 1 | (lag(input) == 1 & lead(input, default = 1) == 1))
)
#    input seq cum_result
# 1      1   1          1
# 2      0   1          2
# 3      1   1          3
# 4      1   2          4
# 5      0   1          5
# 6      1   1          6
# 7      1   2          7
# 8      0   1          8
# 9      1   1          9
# 10     0   1         10
# 11     1   1         11
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very close to what I need. However, I need it to reset the count back 0 when it encounters two 0s in a row. Right now, it just pauses the count and does not add to it when it encounters two 0s. Either way, this is very helpful and I'll try to puzzle out how to do the reset on my own. Thanks!

Comment: Quite welcome! Sorry it missed the mark. I'd suggest updating the sample data in your question to reflect that complexity. Also feel free to unaccept my answer and switch to one of the others if they work fully.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track using `rle`. Using an extended dataset to illustrate the "allowing" part

```
rle_obj <- rle(dfseq$input)

sum(dfseq$input) + sum(ifelse(rle_obj$lengths[rle_obj$values==0]==1,1,0))
[1] 12
```

##### Data

```
dfseq <- structure(list(input = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1), seq = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = "data.frame")

dfseq
   input seq
1      1   1
2      0   1
3      1   1
4      1   2
5      0   1
6      1   1
7      1   2
8      0   1
9      1   1
10     0   1
11     1   1
12     0   1
13     0   2
14     1   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if we all understood the question right and the sample data clarifies not much and blurs any possible mistakes as it all follows the sequence according to OP. To be sure OP could provide a desired outcome and one based on a sample set that includes records that would break the sequence according to his criteria.

I changed the sample data a bit and this is how I interpretted the question.

```
dt <- data.frame(
  input = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)
)

library(data.table)
setDT(dt)

dt[, seq_count := 1:.N, by = rleid(input == 1 | (lag(input) == 1 & lead(input) != 0))]
dt[input == 0 & (lead(input) == 0 | lag(input) == 0), seq_count := NA]

dt

#     input seq_count
#  1:     1         1
#  2:     0         2
#  3:     1         3
#  4:     1         4
#  5:     0        NA
#  6:     0        NA
#  7:     1         1
#  8:     0         2
#  9:     1         3
# 10:     1         4
# 11:     0         5
# 12:     1         6
```